# Get the average scores for the most common (frequent) words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to get the average scores for the most common words in my dataframes. Currently my dataframe has this format.

```
sentence            |    score
"Sam I am Sam"      |      10
"I am Sam"          |      5
"Paul is great Sam" |      5
"I am great"        |      0 
"Sam Sam Sam"       |      15
```

I managed to successfully get the most common words using this blurp of code. This cleaned up my dataframe and removed all stop words. Which yielded me this series.

```
from collections import Counter

nltk.download('stopwords')
df_text = df[['sentence','score']]
df_text['sentence'] = df_text['sentence'].replace("[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}|rt|[0-9]",'',regex=True, inplace=False)
df_text['sentence'] = df_text['sentence'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
top_words =pd.Series(' '.join(df_text['sentence']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:25]
Words     |    Freq
Sam       |     7
I         |     3
Am        |     3 
Great     |     2
is        |     1
```

I understand that the groupby.().mean() is a really important function I would need to use, but I dont understand how I would try to get the score column. This is the ideal output I am trying to get. I showed the math to give logic on how I got the averages.

```
Words     |    Avg
Sam       |     35/7 = 5
I         |     15/3 = 5
Am        |     15/3 = 5
Great     |     5/2 = 2.5
is        |     5/1 = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will skip the data cleaning part (such as stopword removal), except that you really should use `nltk.word_tokenize` instead of `split()`. In particular, it would be your responsibility to eliminate the quotes.

```
df['words'] = df['sentence'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
```

Once the words are extracted, count them and combine with the scores:

```
word_counts = pd.concat([df[['score']],
                         df['words'].apply(Counter).apply(pd.Series)], 
                        axis=1)
```

Now, calculate the weighted sums:

```
ws = word_counts.notnull().mul(word_counts['score'], axis=0).sum() \
                                               / word_counts.sum()
#score    1.0
#``       7.0
#Sam      5.0
#I        5.0
#am       5.0
#''       7.0
#Paul     5.0
#is       5.0
#great    2.5
```

Finally, eliminate the first row that was included only for convenience:

```
del(ws['score'])
```

Answer (score 0):

considering you have your data in a tabular format.. this should work

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cnt = Counter([word for sen in df.sentence.values for word in sen.split()])

for item in cnt:
    tot_score = 0
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if item in row[1]['sentence'].split():
            tot_score += row[1]['score']
    if cnt[item] != 0:
        print(item, tot_score/cnt[item])
    else:
        print(item, 0)
```